# Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7f197e469a60>

Tags: python, django, postgresql, ubuntu-18.04, pg-restore

hi guys i'm working in project with cms called tendenci which required to work with PostgreSQL and python django, I've been working on it on a virtual machine with Ubuntu and when i tried to migrate to production server (with Ubuntu also) i faced a lot of issues the last is migrate the db, actually i did all the required steps but it still showing an error when i try to run the server
this is the command that i run

```html
python manage.py runserver
```

this is the error that i get

```html
Unhandled exception in thread started by <function check_errors.<locals>.wrapper at 0x7fadbc707a60>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
psycopg2.ProgrammingError: relation "site_settings_setting" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "site_settings_setting" WHERE ("site_...
                               ^


The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/autoreload.py", line 228, in wrapper
    fn(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/commands/runserver.py", line 124, in inner_run
    self.check(display_num_errors=True)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 359, in check
    include_deployment_checks=include_deployment_checks,
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/management/base.py", line 346, in _run_checks
    return checks.run_checks(**kwargs)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/registry.py", line 81, in run_checks
    new_errors = check(app_configs=app_configs)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 16, in check_url_config
    return check_resolver(resolver)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/core/checks/urls.py", line 26, in check_resolver
    return check_method()
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 256, in check
    for pattern in self.url_patterns:
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 407, in url_patterns
    patterns = getattr(self.urlconf_module, "urlpatterns", self.urlconf_module)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/functional.py", line 35, in __get__
    res = instance.__dict__[self.name] = self.func(instance)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/urls/resolvers.py", line 400, in urlconf_module
    return import_module(self.urlconf_name)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 994, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 971, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 955, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 665, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 678, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 219, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/var/www/clients/client1/web1/web/mysite/conf/urls.py", line 6, in <module>
    from tendenci.urls import handler500  # noqa: F401
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tendenci/urls.py", line 18, in <module>
    registry_autodiscover()
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tendenci/apps/registry/register.py", line 21, in autodiscover
    import_module('%s.app_registry' % app)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tendenci/apps/entities/app_registry.py", line 18, in <module>
    site.register(Entity, EntityRegistry)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tendenci/apps/registry/sites.py", line 157, in register
    cache_reg_apps(self.get_registered_apps())
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tendenci/apps/registry/sites.py", line 177, in get_registered_apps
    apps = RegisteredApps(self._registry)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tendenci/apps/registry/sites.py", line 44, in __init__
    if check_setting(*setting_tuple):
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/tendenci/apps/site_settings/utils.py", line 156, in check_setting
    scope_category=scope_category, name=name).exists()
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/query.py", line 673, in exists
    return self.query.has_results(using=self.db)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/query.py", line 517, in has_results
    return compiler.has_results()
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 858, in has_results
    return bool(self.execute_sql(SINGLE))
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 899, in execute_sql
    raise original_exception
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/models/sql/compiler.py", line 889, in execute_sql
    cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 79, in execute
    return super(CursorDebugWrapper, self).execute(sql, params)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/utils.py", line 94, in __exit__
    six.reraise(dj_exc_type, dj_exc_value, traceback)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/utils/six.py", line 685, in reraise
    raise value.with_traceback(tb)
  File "/srv/mysite/lib/python3.6/site-packages/django/db/backends/utils.py", line 64, in execute
    return self.cursor.execute(sql, params)
django.db.utils.ProgrammingError: relation "site_settings_setting" does not exist
LINE 1: SELECT (1) AS "a" FROM "site_settings_setting" WHERE ("site_...
```

i don't know if there is a problem with the db or there is somthing else

Comment: Default question: do you have any uncompleted migrations? Run `python manage.py showmigrations`

Comment: when i run this command i get the same error

Comment: and you checked that table actually exists, right?

Comment: yes tables are exists. but i don't know if you asking about a specific table?

Comment: tables are not exists because i cheeked in the virtual machine and i found that not the same tables in the both db. do you know how to recover db in postgreSQL??